# There is no export as SQL option

Tags: phpmyadmin

As CMS I use Wordpress. I want to export a whole category (windows 8) so I run the SQL command :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 15
   AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish');
```

I get the tables but then I cannot export as SQL (there is no option) - strange. Is there a way to export only selected tables as SQL?

[image]

Comment: odds are that it cannot generate the corresponding sql  as it touches multiple tables.  you will need to export each  table to generate the sql.  otherwise,  suck it up and export to csv and  write your loader

Comment: Or you can use SELECT INTO to create a table, populate it with the needed data and then export the table to the SQL dump.

Answer (score 3):

I get this effect only when applying a query.

A table, view, or other direct structure seems to export into SQL fine.

The SQL option seems is not available to a query result set, very sadly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using phpmyadmin 4.8.5 and the export to sql option still not showing.

Two potential workarounds:

1. Create a new table with the results and then export that table:

e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts_export AS
SELECT * FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 15
   AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish');
```

2. Run the query in [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) in the Result Grid select Export button, then switch to .sql file. You will be prompted with a table name to use.

Answer (score -1):

just select the database and visit the export section.
it happens when you select the table only.

Answer (score -1):

its bug or they forgot it 
they have fixed it on [phpmyadmin 4.8.5](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.8.5/) you should update

Answer (score -2):

You should try with this:

```
C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p databasename tablename > C:/filetext.sql
```

(I use XAMPP v3.2.2 and I had the same problem.)

Comment: It seems the question is about exporting the result of a couple of JOINs...